# Getting GPS on Android 2.3.1 and 2.3.3

Tags: android, gps, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I have a problem with the capture of GPS coordinates in the Android emulator 2.3.1 and 2.3.3, I tested and it works the other versions do not understand that in these 2 versions of Android does not read the coordinates, the form I'm doing it to activate the GPS is this:

```
LocationManager lmgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if (!lmgr.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

lmgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 10,this);
```

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

By sending GPS coordinates through the logcat emulator gives the following system and restarts the emulator:

```
01-16 19:09:09.403: E/InputQueue-JNI(320): channel '406f3310 irbu.lod/irbu.lod.mapa.ViewMapaActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-16 19:09:09.403: E/InputQueue-JNI(320): channel '40819c60 irbu.lod/irbu.lod.IRBUActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-16 19:09:09.444: E/InputQueue-JNI(115): channel '406479d8 StatusBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-16 19:09:09.444: E/InputQueue-JNI(115): channel '4063cca0 TrackingView (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-16 19:09:09.444: E/InputQueue-JNI(115): channel '40642858 StatusBarExpanded (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-16 19:09:09.524: E/InputQueue-JNI(137): channel '407d5158 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
01-16 19:10:36.427: E/Zygote(363): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
```

As might do to read the GPS coordinates without reboot?

Comment: When you created the emulator in the AVD, did you make sure that you included GPS as one of it's available features?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I tried putting a component of the GPS hardware but nothing I keep getting the same result, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug as reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13046).

Comment: You are welcome. I'd the same problem, I ended up using API Level 7 (Android 2.1) and everything is fine there. Could you mark my answer as the "right"? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SDK 2.1 .I think this is a bug in android 2.3.1